# How does the specific angular momentum - mass relation arise?

Tags: galaxy

I'm reading about the specific angular momentum - mass relation of galaxies, and I'm confident I understand what the possible reasons are for the difference in specific angular momentum of ellipticals vs. spiral galaxies. But I'm not sure how the relation itself arises. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Related to the $j_h∝M^{2/3}_h$ relation for dark matter halos ?

Comment: It would be useful if you would provide a few of the sources you've already read.